# Pass function as parameter to recursive setTimeout

Tags: javascript, recursion, settimeout

This code does not work:

```
  var counter = 0;

  kick(print);

  function kick(f) {
    setTimeout(function(){
      f();  // problem here;
      kick();
    }, 500);
  }

  function print(){
    console.log(counter++);
  }
```

Browser console gives following error:

> `Uncaught TypeError: f is not a function`

How can I properly call `f()` at the required point?

Comment: The problem is the `kick();` call, you need `kick(f);` again

Comment: You call `kick()` but never pass a parameter to it. Just call it with the argument provided - `kick(f)`

Comment: Btw, you can simply use `setInterval` for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass `f` round again:

```
function kick(f) {
   setTimeout(function(){
      f();  // problem here;
      kick(f);
    }, 500);
 }
```